# Required disabled field`s validation returns false even the input field is filled in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have an input field in a form which is filled but disabled (I am trying to build details view). In the code below `titleAccessor.valid` returns `false`. 
Any ideas how to overcome this issue ?

```
 <div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="title">{{'contentSalesTextConfig.titleForm'|translate}}</label>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            <input [disabled]="pageStatus==4" required [ngClass]="{'redBorder': ((titleAccessor.touched||formSubmitted)&&!titleAccessor.valid)}" [ngModel]="textContentMain.title" #titleAccessor="ngModel" name="title" id="title"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'contentSalesTextConfig.placeHolder.titleForm'|translate}}">
         </div>
 </div>
```

NOTE: When i remove `[disabled]="pageStatus==4"` validation works as it is supposed to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` inputs are considered as invalid inputs , you can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` :

```
<input [readonly]="pageStatus==4" required [ngClass]="{'redBorder': ((titleAccessor.touched||formSubmitted)&&!titleAccessor.valid)}" [ngModel]="textContentMain.title" #titleAccessor="ngModel" name="title" id="title"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'contentSalesTextConfig.placeHolder.titleForm'|translate}}">
```

hope this will help :)